# Is it possible to share Xcode project via git in LAN

Tags: git, macos

We are a team of two persons. Each have a mac. We are developing an iOS project. I am using Git Repository stored locally. The other person wants to be able to access the same project, is it possible to setup git only in our LAN? We can't use the online git because we have to keep it private and at the same time do not have enough resources to pay to keep it private.

Comment: Git lives anywhere there is a Git repository. You could even bypass a 'central sharing repository'. Also, there are some vendors (ie. not github) that hosts private repositories for limited users/space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to set up a central repo on one of the Macs, that both of you configure as the remote:

- In Control Panel, create a new user "git".
- As user git, do this in `/Users/git`: `git init --bare $HOME/project.git`

Now, set up this repo as your remote:

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@localhost/~/project.git
git push -u origin master
```

On the second Mac, do this:

```
git clone ssh://git@mac1/~/project.git
```

Replace `mac1` with the host name of the first mac.